# indenting html code

Tags: html, html-parsing

I have an html file (size about 260kb) whose source code is not formatted. i.e., all the tags and all the code of the html file are on one single line. So, on opening it in gedit(or notepad) its impossible to understand its contents.
Is is possible to somehow indent it according to tags so that all tags come on different lines and the html code becomes comprehendible.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean aside from tabbing yourself?  Try [HTML Tidy Online](http://infohound.net/tidy/) - it has an automatic indentation function.

Comment: No problem - if you're happy can you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 3):

Try out [purehtml.in](http://purehtml.in). It takes care of indenting for HTML tags, including content within `script` and `style` tags.

Answer (score 2):

If it's XHTML, or close to it, you can use these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521265/any-online-xml-formatter-or-formatter-in-free-text-editor

Answer (score 2):

Have you got an IDE to hand? I use Netbeans and generally if I want to format something like that, I'll paste its contents into a new HTML file within Netbeans, hit alt+shift+f to auto-format it, then paste it back to wherever it needs to go.

If not then there's an online tool [here](http://infohound.net/tidy/).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Tidy!](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Visual Studio, the command Ctrl+k+d does it.